# Printing html to pdf using Pechkin (WkHtmlToPdf) is not working

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin

I have a serious problem with `Pechkin` (WkHtmlToPdf).

After converting an html string to pdf for n-times, it won't work anymore.

Does anybody know how can I fix the problem?

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[] HtmlToPdf(string html)
{
    // Create global configuration object
    var gc = new GlobalConfig();

    // A new instance of Margins with x-inch margins.
    gc.SetMargins(new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20))
        .SetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4);

    var pechkin = new SimplePechkin(gc);
    var configuration = new ObjectConfig();

    // Generate the PDF with the given configuration
    var pdfContent = pechkin.Convert(configuration, html);
    pechkin.Dispose();

    return pdfContent;
}
```

In the caller method:

```
var html = "Hi there!";
var pdf = PdfHelper.HtmlToPdf(html);

PdfHelper.DownloadAsPdfFile("MyFileName", pdf);
```

Actually after n-times print, the program is stopped in `Convert` line:

`var pdfContent = pechkin.Convert(configuration, html);`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've found a similar issue, but no real solution, just a workaround. Whenever it stops working (for no reason), I end up stopping IIS and killing w3wp.exe, then I start the IIS server again and it works

Comment: This is what I did, but it's not a definite and good solution!